# The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2DTranspose

Tags: python, keras, deconvolution

Can you help me with this error?

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2DTranspose object at 0x7f5dc629f240>
```

I get this when I try to execute the following line

```
    decoder.add(Deconvolution2D(64, 3, 3, subsample=(1, 1), border_mode='same'))
```

My imports are:

```
from keras.layers import Layer
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.convolutional import Deconvolution2D
```

Comment: This sounds like mixing keras and tf.keras imports, which are not compatible.

Comment: Instead of `keras.layers.convolutional` try only `keras.layers`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Installing Keras](https://keras.io/getting_started/#installing-keras): To use `Keras`, we will need to have the `TensorFlow` package installed. Once TensorFlow is installed.

Now import Keras as shown below

`from tensorflow import keras`

Now `Deconvolution2D`layer has been renamed `Conv2DTranspose` layer.

Now you can import layers as shown below

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2DTranspose
```

For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2DTranspose)